# Cannot find Description (Standard Field) of Case object in fields to display for custom listview

Tags: case, standard-objects, list-view

It is surprising to see that a custom Description (Long Text Area) field with same character limit is available in Fields to Display for a custom list view but the standard field is not available. Does anyone here have any insights around this? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is field `Descrip`? was it a rename of the std field (see right hand Visible Fields list)

Comment: I dont think description field is allowed in list view as these are non sortable as per field properties. Only field which can be sorted can be added in list view. Refer to API guide to check each field properties